# C++ overload operator []

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to implement an indexing with [] for my deque class. I wrote my own class for it .. however, I get an error: "unexpected qualifier-id before '['token ...

maybe I did not quite understand how operator[] works, I can't use the usual indexing with [] for arrays, because I implemented a pointer structure for my deque class...

I divided my class into a .cpp and a .h file - here are the complete files , but maybe only the 
string& Deque::operator[](int i) { method in the .cpp file is interesting...

.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>
#include "ueb3.h"
using namespace std;



enum FunktionsTyp { beenden, pushb, pushf, popb, popf, iter,/*istElement,*/ausgeben};

void menue() {
cout<<endl;
cout<< pushb << ": am Ende einfuegen  " <<endl
    << pushf << ": am Anfang einfuegen  " <<endl
    << popb  << ": letztes Element entfernen  " <<endl
    << popf  << ": erstes Element entfernen  "  <<endl
    //<< istElement <<": Indexweiser Zugriff " <<endl
    << iter <<": Ueber Deque iterieren " <<endl
    << ausgeben << ": Werte ausgeben  " <<endl
    << beenden << ": beenden " <<endl <<endl;
    cout <<"Bitte Zahl eingeben: " ;
}


//"ITERATOR" DEQUE EINMAL DURCHLAUFEN VORNE BIS HINTEN
void Deque::ausgeben()
    {
        if (isEmpty()){
            cout << "Deque ist leer"<<endl;
            return ;
        }
        else
        {
            cout <<"AUSGEGEBEN:\t ";
            Node * tmp = front;
            //cout <<tmp->data<<", ";
            cout <<tmp->getData()<<", ";
            //tmp = tmp->next;
            tmp = tmp->getNext();
            while(tmp != 0){            
                //cout<<tmp->data;  
                cout <<tmp->getData()<<", ";
                //tmp=tmp->next;
                tmp = tmp->getNext();
            }   
            cout<<"\n";     
        }
    }

void iterieren(Deque& d);


int main()
{          
    Deque q;    
    int funktion;    
    string t;
    string s;

    do {
    menue(); 
    cin >> funktion;
    cout <<endl;

    switch (funktion) {
    case pushb : cout << "Wert eingeben: "; cin >> t;
    q.push_back(t);
    break;
    case pushf: cout << "Wert eingeben: "; cin >> t;
    q.push_front(t);
    break;      
    case popb : 
    if (q.isEmpty()) {
        cout <<"Deque ist leer!"<<endl;
        break;
    }
    s = q.pop_back();
    cout <<"Wert entfernt (vom Ende): " <<s <<endl;
    break;
    case popf : 
    if (q.isEmpty()) {
        cout <<"Deque ist leer!"<<endl;
        break;
    }
    s= q.pop_front();
    cout <<"Wert entfernt (vom Anfang): " <<s <<endl;
    break;
    /*case istElement:
    cout <<"Welches Indexelement soll gesucht werden? : "; 
    cin>>o; 
    q.[o];  ;
        */
    break;  
    case iter:
    iterieren(q);
    break;
    case ausgeben :
    q.ausgeben();   
    case beenden : 
    break;
    default : cout << "Falsche Funktion!\n";
    }
    } while (funktion != beenden);


    /*TESTEN DER OPERATOREN
    string aaa = "TEST\t";
    Node * ppn= new Node(aaa);
    cout <<ppn->getData()<<endl;

    Node * n = new Node("hallo");   
    Node p(n);
    cout<<p.getData()<<endl;

    Node * h = new Node("test222"); 

    Node * z = h;
    cout <<z->getData();

    bool same = h==z;
    cout <<"Node z und h gleich? " <<same<<endl;;

    bool same2 = h!=z;
    cout <<"Node z und h nicht gleich? " <<same2<<endl;



    Deque a ;
    a.push_front("erster Wert Deque1");
    Deque b;
    b.push_front("erster Wert Deque2 ");

    Deque c = a+b;
    c.ausgeben();
    Deque d = c+=a;
    d.ausgeben();


    */



return 0;       
}

  bool operator==(Node& a,Node& b) {
      Node * tmp  = &a;
      Node * tmp2 = &b;
      return ( tmp->getData() == tmp2->getData());
  }

    bool operator!=(Node& a,Node& b) {
      Node * tmp  = &a;
      Node * tmp2 = &b;
      return ( tmp->getData() != tmp2->getData());
  }

  Deque& Deque::operator+=(Deque& a) {
      if (this->getFront() == a.getFront()) {
          cout << "Abbruch. Gleiche Deques?"<<endl;
          return *this;
      }

      else{   
      int count1 =0;
      count1 = a.Size();      
      int sum= this->count += count1;     
      this->setSize(sum);

      Node * tmp = a.getFront();
      this->append_Node(tmp);
      this->rear = a.getRear();
  }

      return *this;  

  }

Deque& Deque::operator+(Deque& a){  
    *this += a;
    return *this;
}

/*
string& Deque::operator[](int i) {
    assert( i>=0 && i< this->Size()-1);
    int start = 0;
    string found ;
    if (this->isEmpty()){
                cout<<"Deque ist leer!" <<endl;

    }
    Node * tmp = this->getFront();
    bool gefunden = false;
    while (!gefunden && start < i) 
    {   
        if (start!=i) {         
        tmp = tmp->getNext();
        if (tmp == 0) {
            cout <<"Es existiert kein " << i<<".tes Element" <<endl;

        }
        start++;
    }   
    if ( start == i) {
        string * found = new String(tmp->getData());
        cout <<i << ".ter Wert: " <<found<<endl;
        gefunden = true;
        return * found;     
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
*/

    bool Deque::isEmpty()
    {       
        return count == 0 ? true : false;
    }


     Deque::iterator it;
    void iterieren(Deque& d){   
        if (d.isEmpty()) {
            cout <<"Deque leer!"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        for (Node *it = d.getFront(); it != 0; it = it->getNext()) {    
            cout << it->getData()<<", ";            
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
```

.h file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


class Node
{   
private:
    string data="\0";
    Node* next=0;
    Node* prev=0;

public:

Node(){};



Node(string p){
    this->data = p;
}

//KOPIERKONSTRUKTOR MIT POINTER
Node(Node * n) {
    this->data = n->getData();
    this->next = n->getNext();
    this->prev = n->getPrev();

}

//KOPIERKONSTRUKTOR MIT REFERENZPARAMETER
Node(Node& n) {
    Node * tmp = &n;
    this->data = tmp->getData();
    this->next = tmp->getNext();
    this->prev = tmp->getPrev();
    delete tmp;
}

//ZUWEISUNGSOPERATOR(=)
Node& operator=(Node& n) {
    Node * tmp = &n;
    this->data = tmp->getData();
    this->next = tmp->getNext();
    this->prev = tmp->getPrev();
    return *this;
}



string getData(){
    return this->data;
}  

string getData() const{
    return this->data;
}  

void setData(string v) {
    this->data = v;
}

Node * getNext() {
    return this->next;
}

Node * getNext() const{
    return this->next;
}

Node * getPrev() {
    return this->prev;
}  


Node * getPrev() const {
    return this->prev;
}  


void setNext(Node * n) {
    this->next = n;
}

void setPrev(Node * n) {
    this->prev = n;
}    

};



class Deque
{  
private:
    Node* front;
    Node* rear;
    int count;

public:
    Deque()
    {
        front =0 ;
        rear =0;
        count = 0;
    }   

    typedef Node* iterator;


    //ELEMENT AM ANFANG HINZUFUEGEN
    void push_front(string element)
    {
        // Create a new node
        Node* tmp = new Node(element);
        //tmp->data = element;
        //tmp->next = 0;
        //tmp->prev = 0;

        if ( isEmpty() ) {
            // erstes Element hinzufuegen
            front = rear = tmp;
        }
        else {
            // Ganz vorne anhaengen und Pointer umbiegen
            //tmp->next = front;
            tmp->setNext(front);
            //front->prev = tmp;
            front->setPrev(tmp);
            front = tmp;
        }
        count++;
    }

    //ERSTES ELEMENT ENTFERNEN
    string pop_front()
    {
        if ( isEmpty() ) {          
             cout << "Deque ist leer" <<endl;

        }

        //  Wert aus erstem Knoten holen
        string ret = front->getData();

        // Ersten Knoten loeschen und Wert holen
        Node* tmp = front;
        if ( front->getNext() != 0 )
        {
            front = front->getNext();
            front->setPrev(0) ;
        }
        else
        {
            front = 0;
        }
        count--;
        delete tmp;

        return ret;
    }

    //ELEMENT AM ENDE HINZUFUEGEN
    void push_back(string element)
    {          
        // neuen Tmp Knoten erzeugen
        Node* tmp = new Node();
        //tmp->data = element;
        //tmp->next = 0;
        //tmp->prev = 0;

        tmp->setData(element);
        tmp->setNext(0);
        tmp->setPrev(0);

        if ( isEmpty() ) {           
            front = rear = tmp;
        }

        else {
            // hinten an Liste anhaengen, Pointer umbiegen
            //rear->next = tmp;
            rear->setNext(tmp);
            //tmp->prev = rear;
            tmp->setPrev(rear);
            rear = tmp;
        }

        count++;
    }

    void append_Node(Node * firstNode)
    {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            front = rear = firstNode;
        }

        else 
        {
            rear->setNext(firstNode);
            firstNode->setPrev(rear);
        }
    }

    //LETZTES ELEMENT ENTFERNEN
    string pop_back()
    {
        if ( isEmpty() ) {
             throw "Deque ist leer";

        }

        string ret = rear->getData();

        // letzten Knoten loeschen und Pointer umsetzen
        Node* tmp = rear;
        if ( rear->getPrev() != 0 )
        {
            rear = rear->getPrev();
            rear->setNext(0);
        }

        else
        {
            rear = 0;
        }
        count--;
        delete tmp;
        return ret;
    }


    //PEEK ERSTES ELEMENT
    string getFirst()    
    {          
        if ( isEmpty() )
            cout << "Deque ist leer"<<endl;
        return front->getData();
    }

    //PEEK LETZTES ELEMENT
    string getLast()
    {
        if ( isEmpty() )
             cout << "Deque ist leer"<<endl;
        return rear->getData();
    }

    //ANZAHL ELEMENTE IM DECK ZURUECKGEBEN
    int Size()
    {
        return count;
    }

    void setSize(int size){
        this->count = size;
    }

    //DECK LEER?
    bool isEmpty();


    Node * getFront() {
        return front;
    }

    Node * getRear() {
        return rear;
    }

    //"ITERATOR" DEQUE EINMAL DURCHLAUFEN VORNE BIS HINTEN
    //in der ueb3.cpp Datei implementiert
    void ausgeben();

    Deque& operator+=(Deque& a);

    Deque& operator+(Deque& a);

    void iterieren(Deque& d);


    //string& operator[]( int i);
};
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain the error message includes a line number. You should show us the line the error is coming from.

Comment: Too much code.  Please reduce the example to something bite-sized.

Comment: You should not be getting any errors regarding `operator[]`'s definition with this code ... you have both its declaration and implementation commented out.

Comment: Your `operator[]` dynamically allocates a copy of the string it finds and returns that? That is a bad idea. Why not return a (const) reference to the string you find. At the very least, if you want to return a copy, get rid of the `new` and return the string you find by value.

Comment: The code is way too cluttered - make it short and bring it to the point (including code causing errors)

Comment: +1 on Praetorians comment - The one line which actually uses the operator would already create a memory leak: `q.[o];` (well it won't even really compile since the syntax should be `q[o];` and that's probably your compiler error right there). The reference returned is never stored anywhere and will get lost. 
I see way too many obvious errors without even trying to compile this.

Comment: I catched the reference or the bold string value of course in the menue... but however if it reaches the if case where it says that this element does not exist ... it crashes but it should return in the menue... how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code of your operator[] that is compiled:

```
string& Deque::operator[](int i) {
        // You need to check whether i is in dequeue range, and, if not in range, throw an exception
    assert( i>=0 && i< this->Size()-1);
    int start = 0;
    string found ;
    if (this->isEmpty()){
                cout<<"Deque ist leer!" <<endl;

    }
    Node * tmp = this->getFront();
    bool gefunden = false;

    while (!gefunden && start < i)
    {
        // In this loop we will always find appropriate element
        if (start!=i) {
        tmp = tmp->getNext();
        if (tmp == 0) {
            cout <<"Es existiert kein " << i<<".tes Element" <<endl;

        }
        start++;
    }  
    if ( start == i) {
        break; // OK, we found one
        //string * found = new String(tmp->getData()); // It won't be compiled
        string * found = new string(tmp->getData());
        cout <<i << ".ter Wert: " <<found<<endl;
        gefunden = true;
        return * found;
    }
    }
        return tmp->getDataRef();
    //return 0; This string is buggy
}
```

I have also added function to the Node class. This one is needed to obtain data reference:

```
class Node {
...
std::string& getDataRef() {
        return this->data;
}
...
}
```

Comment: I still have an issue.. after cout <<"element does not exist" the program crashes... is there any way to return safely to the previous menue?        
        if (tmp == 0) {
            cout <<"Es existiert kein " << i<<".tes Element" <<endl;
           break;
        }

Comment: @user2883596 There should be something like `throw std::runtime_error("Empty deque")` following to the `cout<<"Deque ist leer!" <<endl;` code. Also please check my comments it your code.